# Here Maps API - iPad EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: ios, ipad, here-api

My project is working perfectly on any iphone, but when I try to run it on any ipad model I get the following error while defining the mapView.

`var mapView = NMAMapView()` ---> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)

Edit: Device is ipadPro 10.5, iOS v12.1, HEREMaps (3.9.0) installed with cocoapods,  tried both on simulator and real device.

Comment: Please provide us more details like iPad model, iOS version, sdk version, code snippet used for map initialization.

Comment: I have the same issue on iPhone 6 (iOS v10.3.1, HEREMaps 3.10.0) installed with CocoaPods in a Swift project.
It crashes in the init method (with and withouth frame parameter).
Unfortunately (and obviously) SDK symbols are hidden so I cannot understand what is happening.
I'm embedding the NMAMapView in a UIView, added to a presented modally UIViewController.

Comment: This is the stacktrace:

`#0 0x0000000101cf2328 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol57820$$NMAKit ()
#1 0x00000001017345b0 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol28856$$NMAKit ()
#2 0x000000010172d978 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol28694$$NMAKit ()
#3 0x00000001014557ec in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol14298$$NMAKit ()
#4 0x00000001012bea24 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol5973$$NMAKit ()
#5 0x00000001012be5f0 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol5969$$NMAKit ()
#6 0x0000000100208a98 in @nonobjc NMAMapView.init() ()
#7 0x00000001001f622c in NMAMapView.__allocating_init() ()`

Comment: Could attach snip of code on how you exactly initialize sdk and create map?

Comment: SDK was initialized in AppDelegate class with the following code: `NMAApplicationContext.setAppId("app_id", appCode: "app_code", licenseKey: "license_key")`.  
Instead, map view was initialized in a controller with the following code: `let map = NMAMapView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: containerMapView.bounds.width, height: containerMapView.bounds.height))`

Comment: Swift github applications https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples was re-tested on real device iPad 6 gen, and simulator iPad pro (10,5 i) with generated credentials via cocoapods.No described issues found. Please provide your application code, xcode log and crash log details.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "real" solution but it has solved the same issue for me.

In my project's scheme there was a specific "Application Language" selected because I was debugging it.

Removing this setting, the `NMAMapView` starts working again. 

I think that it's related to the Permission Location Access alert, but it's not  reproducible bug (I tried with an empty project and in that case it doesn't happen)

**UPDATE**

I resolved. In my case was related to Location Access authorizations. In certain situations my `NMAPView` was instatiated before asking the authorization for Location Access and this caused the crash.